# System model merge with multiple input and one output

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, function-construction, control-systems

I was curious, and I used the built-in functions of Mathematica to analyze the following scheme:

I used [SystemModelMerge](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemsModelMerge.html) as:

```
integrator = TransferFunctionModel[1/s, s];

sum1 = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{}, u1 + u2}, {}, {u1, u2}];

prod1 = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{}, u1 u2}, {}, {u1, u2}];

sum2 = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{}, u1 + u2}, {}, {u1, u2}];

prod2 = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{}, u1 u2}, {}, {u1, u2}];

n1 = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{}, u^2}, {}, {u}];

nsys = 
 SystemsModelMerge[
  SystemsConnectionsModel[{n1, prod1, sum1, integrator, sum2, 
    prod2}, {{1, 1} -> {2, 1}, {2, 1} -> {3, 1}, {3, 1} -> {4, 1}, {4,
       1} -> {6, 2}, {5, 1} -> {6, 1}, {6, 1} -> {1, 1}, {1, 1} -> {5,
       1}}, {{1, 1}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}}, {{1, 1}}]]

During evaluation of In[126]:= Control`ConnectionsDump`SystemsModelConnect::inputdef: -- Message text not found -- (4)
```

It did not work and it is not clear why. Most likely, a connection error.

Is there a way to improve the results using [SystemModelMerge](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemsModelMerge.html), or some other way that makes it easier to view multiply connected systems with multiple inputs?
For example, in my case, $u_1$ is an arbitrary signal, and $u_2 = u_3 = 0.1 sin (10 t)$?

[image]

Comment: The error message appears to be coming from the SystemModelMerge command - I tried everything you wrote without that and don't see the error.

Comment: I think your inputs should be {{2,1},{3,1},{5,1}}.

Comment: You right. There is mistake in connection. Carelessness...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some mistakes in the specs, like the first input is {2, 2} and not {1, 1}, etc.

```
SystemsModelMerge[SystemsConnectionsModel[
  {n1, prod1, sum1, integrator, sum2, prod2}, 
  {{5, 1} -> {6, 1}, {6, 1} -> {1, 1}, {1, 1} -> {2, 1}, {2, 1} -> {3, 1}, 
       {3, 1} -> {4, 1}, {4, 1} -> {6, 2}, {1, 1} -> {5, 2}}, 
  {{2, 2}, {3, 2}, {5, 1}}, 
  {{1, 1}}]]
```

> [image]

Comment: You right. I had an error in block connections. I need to be more careful.

Comment: NP. We all make such mistakes. Thanks to your example, the error message will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Please, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239610/asymptotic-output-tracking-code-issues